# Data mining find biggest sub segment of dataframe

Tags: python, r, cluster-computing, data-mining

I have a dataFrame that look like this:

```
-----------------------------
| Gender | City | n  | Count| 
-----------------------------
|   M    | SF   | ...| 10   |
-----------------------------
|   M    | NY   | ...| 20   |
-----------------------------
|   F    | SF   | ...| 15   |
-----------------------------
|   F    | NY   | ...| 25   |
-----------------------------
```

Is there any library, (in python preferably) that allow me to cluster using k-means, or something similar taking the "count" metric as a number of observation into consideration?

Thanks

Comment: This is a fairly confusing question: First, " 'n' can be a random number of dimensions" what does that mean? does that mean that each row has an element that is a vector with random length?  I'm also not sure by what you mean by "one dimension and multiple features." This doesn't make any sense either, in most cases the dimension of the problem and the features are the same thing, and k-means can be easily applied to these problems.

Comment: Hi,
thanks for your answer. I still struggle a little bit to use the right terminology. "does that mean that each row has an element that is a vector with random length?" all the rows have the same length but I am trying to find a solution that will work no mater how many "columns" I have. 
To give you an expected output of what I would expect : 
Gender: "F" could be a cluster by itself because the sum of count of F is 40.
An other possible cluster would be F + NY, because it has a count of 25.

Comment: If I understand correctly k-means will give me groups with the same amount of dimensions being present ex: F+SF and F+NY = group 1. I would want to find "groups" that don't necessarily have all the dimensions present but only the most commun attributes across them ex: F could be one group by itself.

thanks

Comment: So I'm a bit confused still, is count the number of duplicate observations?  I think you need to edit your question again and really think about what you are asking and ensure everything is well defined and unambiguous.

Comment: What is a cluster? (Example?) What is a *good* cluster? How do you measure quality? What is "big" (sum of counts?) What is a dimension opposed to a feature (for many people, these are synonyms). Note that many clustering algorithms like k-means don't work well on categorical or textual data.

Comment: Hi, thanks you all for your comment. I re-wrote the question to "simplify" it. I am still having a hard defining correctly the question, and the "expected" results that I want... Hope I made it clearer like that